# How to use an object, save the value into an arrayList, and reuse the same object to keep getting user input

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I am trying to create a SavingsAccount object and then use a method create account to take user inputs (account name, account number, and starting balance) and then store that information into an arrayList to access later.

I was thinking that I could just have one instance of the object (Savings account) save the data into the arrayList and then reuse the object so that I do not have multiple objects ( was thinking this would be more memory efficient).

I am new to Java, and this is homework, I have posted my code below that I have so far.  I also am not exactly sure how I should be using the toString method in order to later print out a list of all the accounts that have been created.

The main problem I am having is how to store the objects data into the arrayList I know to use the .add() however, it seems to be overwriting all the information stored into the array with the last value entered.  So I unsure how to do this, I have read many posts here that are on the same topic or something similar and still do not understand the correct way to do this.

I would welcome any guidance or advice, thank you for taking the time to read my post.

```
   package bankingSystem;

/**
 * 
 * @author xxxx
 *
 */
public class SavingsAccount {
    private String accountNumber;
    private String accountName;
    private double accountBalance;


    /**
     * Constructor to create a new savings account object that takes in a new   
       account number and a new account name
     * @param newAccountNumber
     * @param newAccountName
     */
    public SavingsAccount(String newAccountNumber, String newAccountName){
    this.accountNumber = newAccountNumber;
    this.accountName = newAccountName;
    this.accountBalance = 0;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new savings account with passed in data of new account name,  
       number, and starting balance.
     * @param newAccountNumber
     * @param newAccountName
     * @param startingAccountBalance
     * @return true always as the information is stored in an arrayList and 
       will not fill up.
     */
    public SavingsAccount(String newAccountNumber, String newAccountName,         
    double startingAccountBalance){
        this.accountNumber = newAccountNumber;
        this.accountName = newAccountName;
        this.accountBalance = startingAccountBalance;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the banking account number
     * @return the bank account number
     */
    public String getAccountNumber(){
        return accountNumber;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the requested account name
     * @return
     */
    public String getAccountName(){
        return accountName;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the requsted account balance
     * @return the account balace;
     */
    public double getAccountBalance(){
        return accountBalance;
    }

    /**
     * Changes a bank account name.
     * @param updateAccountName
     * @return the updated value for accountName
     */
    public String setAccountName(String updateAccountName){
        accountName = updateAccountName;
        return accountName;
    }

    /**
     * Deposit funds into account.
     * @param depositAmount
     * @return true, as this would always be true for a realistic amount.
     */
    public boolean deposit(double depositAmount){
        accountBalance += depositAmount;
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * withdraws the specified amount of funds from the account.
     * @param withdrawlAmount
     * @return true if successful, else return false if there is an ISF     
     transaction.
     */
    public boolean withdrawl(double withdrawlAmount){
        if(accountBalance - withdrawlAmount < 0){
            return false;
        }else{
            accountBalance -= withdrawlAmount;
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        StringBuilder results = new StringBuilder();
        results.append("The account number is " + accountNumber + " The 
    account name is " + accountName + " The account balance is " + 
    accountBalance + "\n");
        return results.toString();
    }
}

package bankingSystem;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * 
 * @author xxxx
 *
 */
public class BankingSystem {

public static void main(String[] args) { 
    ArrayList<SavingsAccount> arrayOfSavingsAccounts = new   \
ArrayList<SavingsAccount>();
    int totalNumberOfAccounts = 0;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int menuSelection = 0;
    do{
        System.out.println("\nPlease select from the following options: \n1.    
Create a new account\t\t\t2.  Deposit funds\n3.  Withdrawl funds\t\t\t\t4.  
Transfer funds between accounts\n5.  Display all accounts\t\t\t6.  Exit 
Program\n");    
        if (input.hasNextInt()){
            int temp = input.nextInt();  //used a temp variable to compare the 
if statement below
            if (temp > 0 && temp < 7){
                menuSelection = temp;
            }else{
                System.err.println("INVALID ENTRY, Please try again");
            }
        }else{
            System.err.println("INVALID ENTRY, Please try again");
        }
        input.nextLine();  //used this to clear the value being held in 
scanner
    }
    while (menuSelection < 1 || menuSelection > 6);
    switch (menuSelection){
        case 1:  System.out.println("\t\t\t\tCREATE NEW ACCOUNT:\nPlease enter 
the account holders name: \n");
            String AccountName = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Please enter an account number: ");
            String AccountNumber = input.nextLine();
            if (totalNumberOfAccounts == 0){
                //search for duplicate account number   
            }
            System.out.println("Please enter starting account balance e.g. 
2500.50 :");
            double startingAccountBalance = input.nextDouble();
            SavingsAccount createSavingsAccount = new 
SavingsAccount(AccountNumber, AccountName, startingAccountBalance);
            arrayOfSavingsAccounts.add(createSavingsAccount);
            SavingsAccount createSavingsAccount = new 
    }
}
```

}

Comment: sorry but what trouble are you **actually** having?

Comment: @ScaryWombat I am having trouble (not sure how or what to do) in order to create the object (which I did) and then store the information into the arrayList, and then use that same object in order to take user input for the next account and then save that into the arraylist and so on.

Comment: have you tried the get() method of ArrayList in order for you to use the object? and then declare a data type and put an initialized e.g. SavingAccount sv=arrayOfSavingsAccounts.get(0);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the value stored into the ArrayList is a reference(to the memory location of the object), you must create a new object or all the instances of that referenced object in the ArrayList will be of the same value.

I changed my code to create a new object each time a new account was created and then store the value of the newly created object.

Thank you everyone for your assistance.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help, this is solved as I mentioned earlier I just created a new object when a user created a new account.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the last line:

SavingsAccount createSavingsAccount = new SavingsAccount(AccountNumber, AccountName, startingAccountBalance);

because you initialize a new instance just remove it and then any new operation will overwrite the object old values just it.

Comment: Yes, I removed that.  Thank you, but I am still having the same issues.

Comment: OK then move the initialization line to be the first line of the main method the use this variable

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about just creating  an array of SavingAccounts with a fixed number of accounts?
SavingAccounts[] savingArray;
savingsArray = new SavingAccounts[10];

Comment: I have however, this is for homework, and it needs to be an arrayList as it is unknown how many accounts the user will create.